# my JavaScript using jQuery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small program html and js program

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="temp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='display'></div>
<input type="button" id="creation" value="Create"/>
</body>
```

temp.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#creation').click(function() {
    alert("hi");
  });   
});
```

Can any one help me find the mistake in this above programs. when i click the create button it should alert me "hi". appreciate your help

Comment: You don't appear to have loaded jQuery.

Comment: can you explain little more

Comment: jQuery isn't built-in to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't include jQuery in your code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="temp.js"></script>
```

Make sure it is included before the first reference to `jQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load jQuery.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jQuery then load your `temp.js` script.

Working example with jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#creation').click(function() {
    alert("hi");
  });   
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JQuery</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id='display'></div>
<input type="button" id="creation" value="Create"/> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```