# How to open new page with certain radio inputs checked

Tags: javascript, html

For simplicity, here is an example. I want to have a link from my index page to my Inputs.html with one of the inputs selected.

For example, on the first link I want to open the Inputs page with "red" radio input to be checked, on the second green and so on.

So far only html, js and css are used on site, with some php on server

`Inputs.html`

```
...
<input type="radio" name="color" id="red" value="red" />
<label...>
<input type="radio" name="color" id="green" value="green" />
<label...>
<input type="radio" name="color" id="blue" value="blue" />
<label...>
...
```

Comment: checked="checked"

Comment: That works if I have one page for each link. I need different input to be checked depending on the link I used to visit the same page.

Comment: When writing _HTML_ (not e.g. XHTML), avoid self-closing tags: Void elements like `<input>` mustn't even have a closing tag.

Comment: "_I need different input to be checked depending on the link I used to visit the page_" - can you please give us some examples of how these "links" would look like? I assume you are talking about passing URL search parameters, like: `?color=bue`. Have a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Comment: Links are from index.html to Inputs.html, basically just switching between pages. But I also need certain inputs to be checked when page is opened. 
Some kind of template for user inputs.

Comment: then you have two choices: render different html in the php based on the query parameters, or use javascript to select on the client when it is loaded. Neither are hard to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Query parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) allow the URL to include what radio button should be selected. The radio button can be selected in the backend or the frontend.

Let's say that the query parameter `color=VALUE` (where `VALUE` is a radio button's values) should preselect the matching radio button.

**In PHP** you could select it like this:

```php
<?php $color = $_GET["color"] ?? ""; ?>
<input type="radio" name="color" id="red" value="red"
  <?php if ($color === "red"): ?>checked<?php endif; ?>>
<input type="radio" name="color" id="green" value="green"
  <?php if ($color === "green"): ?>checked<?php endif; ?>>
<input type="radio" name="color" id="blue" value="blue"
  <?php if ($color === "blue"): ?>checked<?php endif; ?>>
```

**In JS** you could select it like this (should you have a reference to the form):

```js
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams("?color=green"); // Example query string
const form = document.forms[0]; // The form reference

if (searchParams.has("color")) {
  const color = searchParams.get("color");
  form.elements.namedItem("color").forEach(radio => {
    radio.checked = radio.value === color;
  });
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="red"><input type="radio" name="color" id="red" value="red"> Red</label>
  <label for="green"><input type="radio" name="color" id="green" value="green"> Green</label>
  <label for="blue"><input type="radio" name="color" id="blue" value="blue"> Blue</label>
</form>
```

Or like this:

```js
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
if (searchParams.has("color")) {
  // Because ID equals value, we can do:
  const radio = document.getElementById(searchParams.get("color"));
  radio.checked = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was making very similar code with URLSearchParams

    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

      const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

      const selectedColor = urlParams.get("selectedColor");

      const colorInput = document.getElementById(selectedColor);
    if (colorInput) {

        colorInput.checked = true;

      }
    });

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="input.php?color=red">Red</a><br/>
    <a href="input.php?color=green">Green</a><br/>
    <a href="input.php?color=blue">Blue</a><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

inputs.php

```
<?php
$color = $_GET['color'] ??'';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="radio" name="color" id="red" value="red" <?php if($color=='red') echo("checked") ?>/>Red<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="color" id="green" value="green" <?php if($color=='green') echo("checked") ?>/>Green<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="color" id="blue" value="blue" <?php if($color=='blue') echo("checked") ?>/>Blue<br/>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to select that radio button and get it checked:

`$("#red").prop("checked", true);`

Comment: Thank you. Does jquery work by default, I just need to insert the snippet in .js file?

Comment: @Maks111 jQuery is not vanilla JavaScript; it is a third-party library. You need to [include jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43397782/13561410) (as a whole!) before it can be used.